# Shift+Enter not working in edit mode in JupyterLab

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter-lab

When in edit mode in JupyterLab on my Win 10 machine, the Shift+Enter shortcut to execute the current cell does not work. The shortcut still works in command mode and no other keyboard shortcuts seem to suffer from this issue. The problem appeared overnight and I can't think of anything that could have caused it (the only change I have made to my system since yesterday was to uninstall my antivirus). I have tried disabling my extensions in Chrome, but that did not solve the problem.

The issue is limited to JupyterLab -- in Jupyter Notebook, Shift+Enter works in both edit and command mode.

Would appreciate any input.